# Batch script to check for network status?

Tags: batch-file, networking

I have a script to launch a few apps when Windows starts, but I want to pause if the WiFi isn't connected yet.  I written this, but it doesn't trigger when the network is up.

```
@echo on
setlocal

set /A cnt = 0

:networkLoop
ping www.google.pt -n 1 -w 1000 1>nul: 2>nul:
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if errorlevel 1 goto networkRetry else goto networkOK

:networkRetry
set /A cnt+=1
ECHO Network not OK (pass %cnt%) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
if /I %cnt% GTR 30 goto networkBad
TIMEOUT /T 2
goto networkLoop

:networkBad
ECHO Try to reset WIFI manually
pause

:networkOK
ECHO doing program loads
start brave
cd  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam" 
start steam.exe
TIMEOUT /T 3 >NUL 2>&1
start Thunderbird

:END

endlocal
```

This just loops, even when I bring the network up.  The ping doesn't return errorlevel 0.

Comment: [A successful PING does NOT always return an %errorlevel% of 0](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dos scripts a bit of a nightmare.  I was able to fix it by changing the IF statement to (added parens):
if errorlevel 1 (goto networkRetry) else goto networkOK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).